# vector style banding while rendering vectors on geoserver

Tags: gis, postgis, geoserver

This is 2.6 million polygons rendering from postgis on geoserver. On almost all zoom levels less than 8, this banding occurs in different variations per zoom level.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image: vector rendering issue on geoserver]

Comment: without knowing how you are styling and fetching the data it is impossible to answer your question. Though I could ask why you even want to display that many polygons at those zoom levels